# vtable problem with cppunit and xcode project

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, vtable, cppunit

I'm trying to build the zxing iphone project and run the test suites that were written in cppunit-1.12.1. I copied the cppunit-1.12.1 code inside the project, and changing the active SDK to 10.5, I am able to build the cppunit and zxingcore targets, but when I try to build the zxingcore-tests target, I get the following errors, which seem to be related to vtables, and a strange warning having to do with the architecture type of a library:

Is there a good way to format this, by basically escaping formatting without having to insert a > infront of every line. I used `<pre>` tags which worked well in the preview, but didn't in the final rendering -- didn't respect formatting and cut the text off. I'll modify the formatting as soon as someone gives me a suggestion.

```
Ld build/Debug/zxingcore-tests normal i386
cd /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -L/Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug -F/Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug -filelist /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/zxingcore-tests.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -lzxingcore -lCppUnit -o /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/zxingcore-tests

ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/local/lib/libCppUnit.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: common::Counted::Counted()has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/BitSourceTest.o
ld: warning: common::Counted::retain()    has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/BitSourceTest.o
ld: warning: common::ArrayRef::~ArrayRef()has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReedSolomonTest.o
ld: warning: std::valarray::operator[](unsigned long)has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReedSolomonTest.o
ld: warning: common::ArrayRef::reset(common::Array*)has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReedSolomonTest.o
ld: warning: common::ArrayRef::ArrayRef(common::Array*)has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReedSolomonTest.o
ld: warning: common::ArrayRef::ArrayRef(common::ArrayRef const&)has different visibility (default) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/Debug/libzxingcore.a(GF256.o) and (hidden) in /Users/andres/src/zxing/iphone/build/ZXing.build/Debug/zxingcore-tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReedSolomonTest.o
```

`....many more of these warnings...`

And now the errors

```
Undefined symbols:
  "vtable for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase", referenced from:
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in BitArrayTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in BitMatrixTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in BitSourceTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in BlackPointEstimatorTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in PerspectiveTransformTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in ReedSolomonTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in DataMaskTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in ErrorCorrectionLevelTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in FormatInformationTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in ModeTest.o
      __ZTVN7CppUnit27TestSuiteBuilderContextBaseE$non_lazy_ptr in VersionTest.o
  "CppUnit::TestLeaf::doGetChildTestAt(int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BitArrayTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BitMatrixTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BitSourceTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BlackPointEstimatorTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in PerspectiveTransformTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller  in ReedSolomonTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCallerin DataMaskTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCallerin ErrorCorrectionLevelTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCallerin FormatInformationTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCallerin ModeTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCallerin VersionTest.o
  "typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCase", referenced from:
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin BitArrayTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin BitMatrixTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin BitSourceTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin BlackPointEstimatorTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin PerspectiveTransformTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin ReedSolomonTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin DataMaskTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin ErrorCorrectionLevelTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin FormatInformationTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin ModeTest.o
      typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCallerin VersionTest.o
  "CppUnit::TestLeaf::countTestCases() const", referenced from:
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BitArrayTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BitMatrixTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BitSourceTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in BlackPointEstimatorTest.o
      vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller in 
`... lots of these errors ... `
CppUnit::assertEquals(qrcode::decoder::FormatInformation const&, qrcode::decoder::FormatInformation const&, CppUnit::SourceLine, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)in FormatInformationTest.o
      void CppUnit::assertEquals(int const&, int const&, CppUnit::SourceLine, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)in ModeTest.o
      void CppUnit::assertEquals(qrcode::decoder::Mode* const&, qrcode::decoder::Mode* const&, CppUnit::SourceLine, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)in ModeTest.o
      void CppUnit::assertEquals(int const&, int const&, CppUnit::SourceLine, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)in VersionTest.o
      void CppUnit::assertEquals(bool const&, bool const&, CppUnit::SourceLine, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)in VersionTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is there any way to format this by simply escaping formatting of the whole thing?

Comment: What's the result of running `file` on /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/local/lib/libCppUnit.dylib?

Comment: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/local/lib/libCppUnit.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

Comment: @Andres: Thanks. Not sure, I think it might be a red herring. See my answer for what I think might be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's what I think the problem is but don't quote me on this ;)

The cppunit code uses a `CPPUNIT_API` macro to wrap up

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

and

```
__declspec(dllimport)
```

when building on Win32. It doesn't use the equivalent

```
__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
```

for `gcc`. This can cause problems when including that code in projects that *do* make use of the visibility attributes in `gcc`, most notably when the project uses the `gcc` command line flag

```
-fvisibility=hidden
```

to make all symbols private to the library by default and then using

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

in place of `__declspec(dllexport/import)` where appropriate. If a symbol, such as a vtable, is marked hidden in just one library, even though it is marked public in all other libraries, then apparently (see the link below) it is marked hidden and you get a linker error.

In your case the linker warnings that you get initially suggest that `zxingcore-tests` is being built with symbols hidden by default (check for that `-f` option when it's building) whereas `xzingcore` itself has them public. The symbols for the cppunit vtables will exist in `cppunit`, `zxingcore` and `zxingcore-tests` but are marked hidden in `zxingcore-test` and so they get hidden.

I think you need to try to find out why the `zxingcore-tests` build is hiding symbols and prevent it from doing that.

For further reading try the [gcc wiki visibility page](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility), particularly the section on "Problems with C++ exceptions" (and follow the link about vague linkage in there as well which shows it applies to vtables too). I'm vaguely familiar with this stuff because I've been bitten by `dynamic_cast` failures across libraries which, in that instance, are caused by the `typeinfo` objects getting hidden by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem resided in the fact that the cppunit and zxingcore libraries were being built for armv6, whilst the zxingcore-tests was being built for an intel architecture. After chaging the configuration setting for zxingcore-tests to NATIVE_ARCH it seems to be compiling fine.

Comment: Actually that does make more sense given that you had linker errors for things other than vtables and typeinfo objects. If only I'd persevered with the simple `file` approach! lol.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar problems using libraries as well.  I've been able to fix the problems by ensuring that the following are set in *both* project's build settings:

Under Target Info - Build - GCC 4.2 - Code Generation:

Ensure that both 'Inline Methods Hidden' and 'Symbols Hidden by Default' are turned off.

This may be a bit of a sledge hammer technique, but it works.  If anyone can suggest a more fine grained way of removing this problem, I'd appreciate it.